# how can i insert multi language data to database in PHP sqlsrv_connect

Tags: php, utf-8, multilingual

i need insert multi language title of files in database.

Almost like:
[image]

my code:

```
$databaseName = "databasename"; 
$connectionInfo = array( "UID"=>$uid, "PWD"=>$pwd, "Database"=>$databaseName , "CharacterSet" => "UTF-8"); 

$title = "مشخصات فایل " .  " Основы теории литературы";

    $conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);
    $tsql = "INSERT INTO  dbo.Product(title) VALUES ('".$title."')";
    $stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $tsql );
```

store in database :

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Storing your data in `utf8_unicode_ci` column would help you to store the data in multi language.

Assuming you are using mysql

```
 ALTER TABLE t MODIFY LTXT CHAR(49) CHARACTER SET utf8;
```

While inserting use `N`

```
   $tsql = "INSERT INTO  dbo.Product(title) VALUES (N'".$title."')";
```

Comment: `ALTER TABLE dbo.MyTable ALTER COLUMN LTXT
            nvarchar(100) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS NOT NULL`

Comment: Command(s) completed successfully. But after insert not changed...

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8zSYh.png

Comment: Tanks a lot.
solve the problem.
Can you explain more about this?

Comment: you can have a look at [ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/392916/do-i-have-use-the-prefix-n-in-the-insert-into-statement-for-unicode ]